# SUM function in power bi showing the wrong value in Visual(LINE AND STACKED COLUMN CHART) but displaying correct value in the CARD

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Example: You can see the measure [Fig 2] value should be 3 on top on the column instead it's highlighted at 2 [Fig 5].

The measure should add the value 1+2=3 just like [Fig 1] and show on top

Testt - Table name,
Values-Column1,
Success-Column2,
total test - Measure name [Fig 4]

[image: total]
[image: Measure i created to add "Values"]
[image: 2 columns, created measure "total test" based on values column]
[image: Total should be 3]

Comment: Can you make it with a more simple example. Please remove columns that do not take part in your issue. Please check it with values like 1 and 1 for each row, and see if it add up to 2.

Comment: No I mean this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you expect the bar chart to show something else? You have deleted the whole previous question, so now it is hard to guess.

Comment: You made a good way towards simplicity:-) Please clean your post a bit so we can vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me state the problem. How to make a line and stack column chart that will show

1. sales split by category, say by products, on the bars
2. total sales with lines, at the top of the bars.

You need two measures:

For bars (column values):

```
sales = SUM( T[value] )
```

For lines (line values):

```
sales_total = CALCULATE( SUM( T[value] ), REMOVEFILTERS( T[product] ) )
```

The sales_total which you put on the line is supposed to return the sum of all products so we need to remove the "row context".

[image]

Comment: Wow!  thank you so much, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I have been going mad for 3 days. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you tell why you created second measure and removed the filter ?